# SAML 2.0 properties in application.yml

Tags: spring-security, okta, spring-security-saml2

I have been using some tutorials to understand what properties must be set in the application.yml. There does not seem to be any documentation on the complete set of properties that can be set. Here's an example

```
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          samlexample:
            signing:
              credentials:
                - private-key-location: "classpath:credentials/private.key"
                  certificate-location: "classpath:credentials/certificate.crt"
            decryption:
              credentials:
                - private-key-location: "classpath:credentials/private.key"
                  certificate-location: "classpath:credentials/certificate.crt"
            identityprovider:
              singlesignon:
                sign-request: false
#              metadata-uri: https://dev-2148273.okta.com/app/exk2iacdpvAt1bS3D5d7/sso/saml/metadata
                metadata-location: "classpath:okta-metadata.xml"
```

Does anyone know of documentation related to which SAML properties I can set ? For example the last property is not correct. Instead of a URI, I wanted to create a file with the metadata and use that in the application.yml but I dont know what the property name is.

It would be helpful to have a webpage with documentation on the SAML 2 properties that can be set in application.yml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can deduce the full number of parameters in the class `RelayingPartyRegistration` which is what a registration is instantiated into:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.3/api/org/springframework/security/saml2/provider/service/registration/RelyingPartyRegistration.html

As a matter of fact, there are ways in which you instead of adding properties add the registration as a class manually in which case this restriction should be obvious. Check example 130 here : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-saml2login-sansboot

Comment: Thanks ! This is definitely helpful. I might have to look at the Spring Security code directly to see how this mapping is done from yml to class. I definitely prefer to set the attributes in the YML.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to create a file with the metadata and use that in the
> application.yml but I dont know what the property name is.

I was able to use the `file:///` URI prefix for the same `metadata-uri` property value.  For example, a metadata file on a different Windows computer:

```
metadata-uri: file:///\\server\share_name$\path\to\file\metadata.xml
```

You might be able to adapt that for a file on the same server and provide only the absolute path.

> I have been using some tutorials to understand what properties must be
> set in the application.yml. There does not seem to be any
> documentation on the complete set of properties that can be set

My sympathies, I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the properties from the Spring Security config.xsd (this does not refer to the XML configuration, you can get the properties there):
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/main/config/src/main/resources/org/springframework/security/config

E.g. you can check the RNC file of Spring Security 6.1:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/config/src/main/resources/org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-6.1.rnc#L683

Or the XSD:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/config/src/main/resources/org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-6.1.xsd

Of course you still have to do some translation, but I think since you know already some properties it is rather trivial for you to do.

On the location of files - I agree, but I think it is:

```
metadata-location: file:/home/user/okta-metadata.xml
```

as others have pointed out, you can also use metadata-uri with file:/// ...
Note metadata-location does NOT have // after file: